# Put the cursor to the table with Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

```html
<table id="z" border="1" width="20px" contenteditable>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>     
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How to put the cursor to this cell (=table) using Javascript - as it works after a usual click? So after that, keyboard printing should work there. `focus()` doesn't work, but it works with `<input>`.

The expected result:
[image]

**I use Google Chrome.**

Comment: `document.getElementById("z").focus();` maybe?

Comment: @obscure Read more attentively. I have said that `focus()` doesn't work.

Comment: I saw what you wrote. Even more, I've tested what I wrote before actually writing and apparently the cursor blinks after executing the above line.

Comment: @obscure We can test this via `console` and `setTimeout`. After this, I see focus blue highlighting, but no cursor and can't print.

Comment: @oleedd maybe this is browser-specific. At least in FireFox it works flawlessly.

Comment: @obscure I use Chrome. Browser compatibility is bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set focus on div contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388164/set-focus-on-div-contenteditable-element)

Comment: @CBroe No, but thanks. There is `div` and here is `table`. So these questions are similar but not the same.

Answer (score 0):

But it works!

```js
let el = document.getElementById('z');
if (el !== null) {
    el.focus();
}
```

```html
<table id="z" border="1" width="20px" contenteditable>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I use Chrome and I see the focus blue highlighting, but no cursor and can't print.

Answer (score 0):

As its a browser compatibility issue for `focus()` on an `documentElement`, Better you get the bug [467043](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467043) resolved from Chrome.

Comment: It is said there that `focus()` doesn't work, but in my case, it works (because I see highlighting), but no cursor.