# focus/select next text field automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a code that I am using in my current project. There are two fields to enter numbers each allows max 3 digits. I would like to automatically switch to second text field on completing first field with 3 digits. How can I do that ?

I found lots of example for input fields but as here I am using `<td>` I couldn't find a solution myself.

https://jsfiddle.net/shijilt/54918g3s/

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="content mb-0 mt-3">
<div class="row mb-0">
<div id="add-product">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><h6 class="font-14"><strong>Number</strong></h6></th>
                <th><h6 class="font-14"><strong>Count</strong></h6></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_number_3" data-length="3" class="test"><h3 class="color-green-dark mb-0"></h3></td>
        <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_count_3"data-length="3" class="test"><h3 class="color-red-dark mb-0">1</h3></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    

</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$('td[contentEditable="true"]').on("keydown", e => {
  // define allowed keys
  const allow = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Tab', 'Backspace']
  // get pressed key
  const k = e.key
  if (allow.includes(k)) {
    // get the value before this keydown
    const val = e.target.textContent

    // determine the limit according to your logic
    const limit = Number(e.target.dataset['length']);

    if (val.length == limit && 'Tab' != k && 'Backspace' != k) {
      // pressing this key would put the value over the limit
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('deny: ' + k, val, limit)
    } else
      console.log('allow: ' + k, val, limit)

  } else {
    // key not allowed
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('deny: ' + k)
  }

})
</script>
```

Comment: What's the reason you are not using input fields?

Comment: try using `val.trim().length`, your `td` textContent contains a lot of empty spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set focus on div contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388164/set-focus-on-div-contenteditable-element)

Comment: Just look for a "set focus on contenteditable" element and for a "how to detect when an input has 3  digits". `input` and `contenteditable` works almost the same actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `trim()` on `val`, because your div text contains many empty spaces:  `val.trim().length`.

Then, you can move the focus on the next `td` with `$(this).next('td')[0].focus()` where you check the length of the input.

```js
$('td[contentEditable="true"]').on("keydown", function(e) {
  // define allowed keys
  const allow = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Tab', 'Backspace']
  // get pressed key
  const k = e.key
  if (allow.includes(k)) {
    // get the value before this keydown
    const val = e.target.textContent


    // determine the limit according to your logic
    const limit = Number(e.target.dataset['length']);



    if (val.trim().length == limit && 'Tab' != k && 'Backspace' != k) {
      // pressing this key would put the value over the limit
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('deny: ' + k, val, limit)
      if ($(this).next('td').length > 0) {
        $(this).next('td')[0].focus()
      }
    } else
      console.log('allow: ' + k, val, limit)

  } else {
    // key not allowed
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('deny: ' + k)
  }

})
```

```css
#add-product table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

#add-product table th {
  text-align: center;
}

#add-product table td {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#list-product table {
  width: 100%;
}

#list-product table th {
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 2px solid;
  text-align: left;
}

#list-product table td {
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
  text-align: left;
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content mb-0 mt-3">
    <div class="row mb-0">
      <div id="add-product">
        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <h6 class="font-14"><strong>Number</strong></h6>
              </th>
              <th>
                <h6 class="font-14"><strong>Count</strong></h6>
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_number_3" data-length="3" class="test">
                <h3 class="color-green-dark mb-0"></h3>
              </td>
              <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_count_3" data-length="3" class="test">
                <h3 class="color-red-dark mb-0">1</h3>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late contribution to an already answered question. I am posting it here since I spent some time on putting it together.

The main effort went into *accepting* the non-ideal markup as it is (having `contenteditable` elements with nested elements inside them) and making it safe against any kind of user input. A common problem of contenteditable elements with *nested internal structures* is that the user can easily delete anything that is defined inside the structure. It would be very hard to provide safeguards against this from happening. Instead I decided to manipulate the DOM by transferring the `contenteditable` and other related attributes to the closest nested elements that don't have any children. It is these elements that I then collect in the array `eds` (editable elements).

In the second part I then add event listeners for the "input" event unto the elements of `eds`. I chose "input" over "keyup" as it also takes care of mouse triggerred paste events.

```js
// Preprocessing: transfer contenteditable attributes to innermost child elements:
const eds=[...document.querySelectorAll("tbody [contenteditable=true]")].map(e=>{
  // find the innermost childless element:
  const ed=e.querySelector("*:not(:has(*))");
  if (ed){
   e.getAttributeNames().filter(a=>a!="class").forEach(a=>
    (ed.setAttribute(a,e.getAttribute(a)),
     e.removeAttribute(a)))
  }
  return ed ?? e;
});

eds.forEach((c,i)=>c.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 const l=c.dataset.length,cl=c.textContent.length;
 if(cl>=l){
  // set cursor into next editable field (at the end of the input string):
  setCaret(eds[(i+1)%eds.length]);
  // limit the input to l digits:
  c.textContent=c.textContent.slice(0,l);
 }
}));  

function setCaret(el) {
  const range = document.createRange(),
    sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el,el.childNodes.length); 
  sel.removeAllRanges()
  sel.addRange(range)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="content mb-0 mt-3">
<div class="row mb-0">
<div id="add-product">
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><h6 class="font-14"><strong>Number</strong></h6></th>
                <th><h6 class="font-14"><strong>Count</strong></h6></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_number_3" data-length="3" class="test"><h3 class="color-green-dark mb-0">78</h3></td>
        <td contentEditable="true" inputmode="numeric" data-id="lot_count_3"data-length="3" class="test"><h3 class="color-red-dark mb-0">1</h3></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```